# porting heatmaps from Bing 6.3 to Bing V8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, heatmap

I am having problem in migrating old V6.3 bing code for heatmap to new Bing v8. I was using VETileSourceSpecification for creating a tile with url.  `tileSourceSpec = new VETileSourceSpecification(tileId, tileUrl);`

How can I achieve the same in new Bing maps API. I know we have an option to create heatmap. But not sure how to migrate my earlier approach to new one with least modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps v6.3 didn't have a heatmap API, it looks like you were using a tile layer. In Bing Maps V8 you will use the TileLayer class along with the TileSource class. Here are some resources:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712660.aspx
- https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#tileLayerQuadKey+JS

One the big main differences to look out for is that the placeholders for the map tile URL is different. A list of the supported placeholder values are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712690.aspx

Comment: Yes rbrundrit. I am using TileLayer and Tile source class. Can you give me more insight about map tile URL. I am having problem in getting data from URL itself. How do we modify URL to fit it in new map API.

Comment: I want to know about use of %4 and %2 placeholders in old Bing maps. Also their substitute in new API.

Comment: Replace those values with the following: %2 => {subdomain} and %4 => {quadkey}